# LNK2019 (unresolved external symbol) when linking against built dynamic library in QT

Tags: c, qt, visual-studio-2013, dll, linker

I am using QT 5.5.0 within QtCreator to build a C++ application (referenced to as "the application" from now on) which I am trying to link against dynamic link C library ("the library"). All methods which originate from this library cannot be found by the linker when building the application, example output for one method:

```
error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) int __cdecl rlwe_FFT_CTX_init(struct fft_ctx *)" (__imp_?rlwe_FFT_CTX_init@@YAHPAUfft_ctx@@@Z) referenced in function [...]
```

The library is imported by the following statement in the .pro file:

```
LIBS += "-L$$_PRO_FILE_PWD_/../../Libraries/rlwekex/Build/rlwekex/Release/Win32/" -lrlwekex
```

I expect this to work, since qmake is running fine and the linker will output another error if I change this to a non-existent library name. Both the application and the library are 32 bit.

The .lib and .dll files for the library have been built by myself using Visual Studio 2013. The same header files are used for building the library and as includes inside the application. A compile switch will mark methods as `__declspec(dllexport)` or `__declspec(dllimport)` using the following code:

```
#  ifdef RLWEKEX_DLL_EXPORT
#   define RLWEKEX_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#  else
#    define RLWEKEX_EXPORT __declspec(dllimport)
#  endif
```

The macros are correctly evaluated in both the library (export) as well as the application (import). The signature of the example method would be as follows:

```
RLWEKEX_EXPORT int rlwe_FFT_CTX_init(FFT_CTX *ctx);
```

Using dumpbin I can verify that the method is actually exported to the .lib - corresponding /HEADERS entry:

```
  Version      : 0
  Machine      : 14C (x86)
  TimeDateStamp: 563B4D17 Thu Nov 05 13:35:35 2015
  SizeOfData   : 0000001F
  DLL name     : rlwekex.dll
  Symbol name  : _rlwe_FFT_CTX_init
  Type         : code
  Name type    : no prefix
  Hint         : 2
  Name         : rlwe_FFT_CTX_init
```

I have another Visual Studio 2013 project which is a test suite (written in C) for this particular library, which is linking against it just fine! QtCreator and Visual Studio 2013 are running on the same machine and are both using the same compiler toolkit (msvc).

Now of course my question: What could be the reason that I can link against the library in the VS2013 test suite, but not in the QT project? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ mangles names of functions while C does not.

The header file for the library needs to contain, near the beginning of the file, something like:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
```

and near the end of the header file

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Note: the above lines are between the 'include guards', not to replace them
.

Comment: Thank you so much! That was exactly what was missing. I didn't know about the different name mangling yet.